# How can I make a struct receive a variable that isn't a System variable

Tags: c#, struct

I have a struct for music notes name MNote , but it takes strings, meaning when I want to make a new note I have to type `MNote S = "C#";`

Is there any way I can make the notes a variable like a system variable, so I'll be able to type `MNote S = C#;` and C# will get recognised as an MNote instead of as a string that gets pushed into an MNote?

Comment: Can you show a bit more code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: `C#` isn't a valid identifier in C# (ironically or otherwise) because `#` is reserved for preprocessor directives, so this syntax will never be in the cards. Sorry. You could have a `CSharp` variable, but that's hardly an improvement over `"C#"`.

Comment: Make an enum for your notes and a constructor which takes it. You can also provide an [implicit-cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) operator from this enum to your struct. Then you can write: `MNote S = Note.CSharp`

Comment: as suggested by @Rango you could declare an [Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) containing the declarations for all music notes you need, although that would require you to know all possible notes beforehand.

Comment: But for the record, you still can't use special characters in enum members. You'd have to call them Csharp with a DisplayName attribute of "C#". Not what you asked but due to limitations as stated in the other comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [pm100's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783972/5389131) and in the comments, an `enum` is the right tool for the job. The aforementioned answer illustrates the basic usage, but I want to add two things that allow you to come even closer to being able to write `MNote S = C#;`

#### Use Unicode letters in your `enum`

While it's true that you cannot use special characters in an `enum` – with the underscore `_` being the only exception, enum members can make use of Unicode letters. While you cannot perfectly mimic the `#` character, you can come pretty close with the [Ogham alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogham#Unicode). The Ogham letter **Gort**, unicode number U+168C, looks like this `ᚌ`.

So you can write

```
public enum MusicalNotes
{
    C,
    Cᚌ,
    D,
    Dᚌ,
}
```

#### Take advantage of the [`using static` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) in C# 6.0 and up

If you dislike having to write something like `var myNote = MusicalNotes.C` you can add a `using static` directive to resolve this.

`using static` allows you to import static members. So adding `using static MusicalNotes;` to your directives you will be able to write `var myNote = C;`.

#### End result

`var myNote = Cᚌ;` is valid code.

Answer (score 1):

Use an enum

```
public enum Notes
{
    C,
    CSharp,
    D,
    DSharp,
...
}
```

Now you can have

```
Notes n1 = Notes.C;
...
if(myNote == Notes.FSharp)
   ....
```

Note (excuse the pun) you cannot have `C#` as you are not allowed special characters in names

And of course you can do

```
class Composition
{
   List<Notes> noteArray;
   ...
}
```